# Drupal 8 render same page header title content in all pages

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-8

I'm having an issue with drupal 8 that it render one page title in all pages. and when i clear cache and i pick an other page to enter in first it keep its title and all other pages

Example:

After clearing cache: I enter in Contact page -> it keep its title in all other pages "Conatct"

clearing cache again: it keep the recent active page title in all other pages

any help.

**Update**
[image]

Comment: Are you rendering the page title through any block. Then the block should be caching and on that case you should write cache contexts for that block.

Comment: I'm using a purchased template, i'll attach the page-title.html.twig that render title

Comment: is the issue happening with other themes? how the title is displayed? you may look for your blocks and try to disable blocks which you don't need in the purchased theme

Comment: Thanks man that helped a bit, the problem is in render function within core cache thing

Comment: I think the main issue comes from the core so an update could fix it for good, Thanks guys.